# How to retrieve xml nodes elements attributes values in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xml

I need retrieve the xml nodes elemente attributes values using for loop in asp.net ....thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

depends on the .Net version you are using.

LINQ to XML is one way to go: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx

Or if you are using older version .Net, XmlDocument with XPath is one way to go: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I'm mostly using .Net 2 and I like just use XPath to do SelectNodes on XmlDocument

Answer (score 0):

For a .NET 2.0 solution please see example below:

My input file is called books.xml and it's stored int the Properties.Resources of my sample project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<books>
<book Title="Rage of angels" Author="Sidney Sheldon">Book 1</book>
<book Title="If tomorrow comes" Author="Sidney Sheldon">Book 2</book>
<book Title="Stranger in the mirror" Author="Sidney Sheldon">Book 3</book>
<book Title="A studyin scarlet" Author="Sir Arthur Conan Doyle">Book 4</book>
</books>
```

Below is the actual code which processes the xml document and writes the value of the Title attribute to the Output Window in Visual Studio. Simply change the code to cater for your xml file and you're good to go:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    document.LoadXml(Properties.Resources.books.ToString());
    ProcessXml(document,"/books/book", "book", "Title");
}

private void ProcessXml(XmlDocument document,string xPath,string elementName,string attributeName)
{
    XmlElement root = document.DocumentElement;
    XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes(xPath);
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
    {
        string attribute = nodes[i].Attributes[attributeName].Value;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(attribute);
    }
}
```